# where i can show my app likes in facebook page?

Tags: facebook-like

I have a facebook app with 3800 likes, and i want to show it in a facebook fan page or app page.

I created a page but the page doesn't work ...

The site is : http://www.pagine-mail.it

and the app page is https://www.facebook.com/pages/Paginemail/598791650162031?fref=ts

(Paginemail in search box)

How can i do it?

Comment: You can’t – likes for Fanpages and for external pages are two different things.

Comment: ok but i have a like button in page that display 3800 likes.

Comment: I can't display this number inside facebook ?

Comment: No, you can not just display any arbitrary content inside a Facebook page. (Some time ago, when Facebook removed the ability to publish news to the users who liked external pages, they offered the possibility to “merge” those external likes to fan pages, but that is not possible any more.)